# Objectify: bulk delete taking way longer than save

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify

Batch deleting of 28,000 entities takes 154 seconds but saving the same entities takes 22 seconds. The entities have an @Id and a few @Index but are otherwise unremarkable POJOs. It's pretty much exactly as specified in the [documentation](https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/Queries#Executing_Queries)

Delete:

```
List<Key<T>> keys = ofy().load().type(clazz).keys().list();
ofy().delete().keys(keys);
```

Save:

```
Map<Key<Object>, Object> mappy = ofy().save().entities(objects).now()
```

Is this expected? This seems way too slow for a delete. I'm running this in a dev environment using RemoteAPIOptions (on the same machine - separate code to handle batch uploads)

Comment: Don't take local dev server as any indication of a real production performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not surprising; delete is usually the slowest operation in the datastore.